# android Service recreating and overlapping

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-intentservice

When I start the app the value in the counter is posted for every 1000ms. The service is kept running even when the app is closed or screen is locked but when i start the app again the service is recreated and I see the counter starting from 0 and it shuffles between the old counter value and the new.

So I see 2 values - New counter & Old counter values updating at the same time and overlap.
How do I eliminate the new counter (or stop the service from recreating)

This is my service running in the background

```
package com.myexample.serviceexample;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class myservice extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "serviceexample";
    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.myexample.serviceexample";
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Intent intent;
    int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);    
    }

    @Override
      public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
        handler.postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI,1000);
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }


    private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            DisplayLoggingInfo();           
            handler.postDelayed(this,1000); 
        }
    };  

    private void DisplayLoggingInfo() {
        Log.d(TAG, "entered DisplayLoggingInfo");

        intent.putExtra("time","some text" );
        intent.putExtra("counter", String.valueOf(++counter));
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

This is my activity code

```
package com.myexample.serviceexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        intent = new Intent(this, myservice.class);

    }

    public void onClick(View view) {

    }

    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            updateUI(intent);       
        }
    }; 

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();        
        startService(intent);
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(myservice.BROADCAST_ACTION));
    }
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();        
        startService(intent);
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(myservice.BROADCAST_ACTION));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        stopService(intent);         
    }

    private void updateUI(Intent intent) {
        String counter = intent.getStringExtra("counter"); 
        String time = intent.getStringExtra("time");
        Log.d(TAG, counter);
        Log.d(TAG, time);

        TextView txtDateTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);      
        TextView txtCounter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        txtDateTime.setText(time);
        txtCounter.setText(counter);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly fine now.

Changes I have made:

1. Delete onPause() function
2. Delete startService(intent) from onResume() so that it does not recreate everytime I open the app
3. Put startService(intent) in the onCreate() function